# Compress request post body Axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I'm creating a react-web app that must call a post REST post endpoint on Firebase Cloud functions, the only problem is that the typical request that will go through will exceed the 10mb limit:

```
/**
   * Create a new flyer inside the storage.
   * @param {String} adminID [Identifier of the admin issuing the request]
   * @param {Object} flyer [Flyer to upload in the storage]
   * @returns {Object} [Containing the response]
   */
  postFlyerAsync(adminID,flyer){
    return new Promise((res,rej)=>{
      const URL = endpoint + "postFlyer";
        return axios
        .post(URL,flyer, { params: { adminID: adminID } })
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response)
          return res(response.data);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          return rej(err);
        });
    })
  }
```

does it exist a way to compress the body? I've tried a million different npm packages but they are either not compatible with webpack config or too slow...any suggestions?

Comment: Firebase isn't meant for file storage. You instead store the file somewhere meant for storing and serving files (such as Google Cloud Storage) and then store a reference to that file in Firebase. See [Cloud Storage for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage)

Comment: The endpoint is connected to the storage through the cloud functions for securty reason. The average post request will contain 20-30 jpeg images encoded in base64, so I really cannot change the architecture.

Comment: Does it have to be base64? Base64 increases the size x1.33 (every three bytes in the original are converted to four bytes in base64). Compression won't get you anything since JPG are already compressed. All other options involve changing the back end in some way.

Comment: Maybe I can try something different beside base64 ... any idea?

Comment: Send as binary. (If you're receiving them as base64, decode them before uploading.) As I said, JPG are already compressed so further compression attempts won't get you anywhere.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I’ll try 

Answer (score 1):

No amount of compression will solve your problem.

You can achieve the same security without opening up your storage by having your endpoint return a signed upload url. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls

Comment: Thanks for the help, for now I will try Ouroboru’s solution because is the one that will take the smaller effort possible

Comment: For any base64 payloads that were 10-13mb, sending them in binary instead might help, but it's not a solution.